# Как правильно реализовать переопределенный метод из Interface?

Tags: java, интерфейс

Метод:

```java
@Override
public void addProduct(String product, int quantity) {
    ...
}
```

Метод из interface:

```java
void addProduct(String product, int quantity);
```

Comment: Переформулируйте свой вопрос. Не ясно, что вы хотите.

Comment: @Override
    public void addProduct(String product, int quantity) {
        addProduct(product, quantity);
    }  Разобрался все сам сделал.

Comment: Нет, не разобрался и не сделал. Этот код вызовет ошибку "Stack Overflow".

Comment: Смотрите, по логике ваш класс (из вопроса, который вы удалили) должен хранить какие-то продукты с их количеством. При вызове метода addProduct нужно добавить продукт куда-то, например, в список. Значит в классе должно быть внутреннее поле списка этих продуктов. И где-то еще нужно хранить количество. В целом, я бы сделал поле типа `HashMap<String, Integer>`, где ключи - названия продуктов, значения - количество. А дальше все методы класса с этим полем взаимодействуют - добавляют в него ключи значения, получают список ключей, и т.д.

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста, можно хотя бы один пример реализации что бы я понял. Не могу найти или уже голова не соображает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Допустим, у нас имеется интерфейс `Market`. У него есть метод `addProduct()`. Если метод не `default`, то мы пишем ему только параметры, без тела. После чего, при имплементации данного интерфейса, мы должны будем(обязаны) реализовать все методы интерфейса.

Пример:

```java
public interface Market {

   void addProduct(String product, int quantity);

}
```

Есть класс работника магазина, который реализует данный интерфейс и его методы, соответственно:

```java
public class MarketWorker implements Market {

   @Override
   public void addProduct(String product, int quantity) {
      System.out.println("Продукт: " + product + " имеется в количестве: " + quantity + " штук.")
   }
}
```

Теперь, если в классе `Main` вызовем данный метод у работника и передадим параметры, он выведет нам переопределенный метод:

```java
public class Main {
   public static void main(String[] main) {
      
      MarketWorker worker  = new MarketWorker();
      worker.addProdct("Сыр", 5);
   }
}
```

Comment: спасибо Вам огромное))))Очень помогло